# user-password disable not working in Ubuntu 12.04, can not start service

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

I need to set up SSH tunnels from Ubuntu on system start. I have scripts that work well under Debian squeeze. Under Ubuntu though, the su command requires to enter a user password which breaks the startup script.

In detail:
Within the daemon start-script autossh is started with a specific user per tunnel.
These users are created before with
`adduser ... --disabled-password`

The following line in the startup script:

`su -s /bin/sh $USER -c "$AUTOSSH $TUNNEL"`

generates a prompt for password (under Ubuntu), even though the tunnel user's PW should be disabled. This stops the script so the service is not started.

I already tried to delete the tunnel user's PW (in case there was some std PW created during creation) but this did not change anything.
Web search did not bring a solution.
If required I could supply a password as a parameter for the su command, but could not find such an option.

Any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this is to [use sudo when scripting for another user](https://serverfault.com/a/407921/3139). That will allow you specifically designate not using a password and allow transition to a password-locked user.

Comment: Thanks - I have put the following into sudoers:

`# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
me      ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
%tunnels ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
root    ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`

still, the scriptline below triggers a password prompt:

`sudo su -s /bin/sh $USER -c "$AUTOSSH $TUNNEL"`

Comment: @sebut `sudo -u $USER command arguments`